# OAuth flow to authenticate user through phonegap and server side

Tags: javascript, cordova, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0

I have seen both phonegap authentication and JS based server application authentication.
I am trying to build a phonegap application for my J2EE ecommerce application. J2EE application gives a rest based api to for my phonegap application. I want to use OAuth authentication so user will be prompted in mobile screen for authentication, how this can be achieved?

I have knowledge about oauth authentication via JS, but question how to make sure J2EE aplication is getting proper authenticated users request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Stormpath's [Servlet Plugin](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/) in your webapp.  This implements the JS client + OAuth token authentication flow for you as [documented here](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/http-request-authentication.html#token-authentication).

When the JS client gets the returned token, it is also returned in an HTTPS-only (secure, http only) cookie.  All future requests to your application will retain that token and send it - the server plugin knows how to look at the token, verify the digital signature, and 'bind' the user account identity to the request.

This allows you to securely identify which user is making a given request *without* using server side sessions (no server-side state = highly scalable).  As long as you use HTTPS from login until the user logs out, you can trust the identity.

Comment: Thanks Les, I did not use the plugin, but this helped me to understand the flow. I used [link](https://github.com/gary-rowe/DropwizardOpenID) code with inAppBrowser for phonegap. Genrated first time permanent token for specific device and a session token. Posted back permanent token to mobile.
Next time whenever session token expires I use permanent token with device id to get new session token, this way I am not making user to login again via google OAuth.

Comment: @sanjaypatel glad to hear that it helped present an avenue to a solution!